# hide half of a div with overflow is'nt working

Tags: html, css

i've used overflow property to make the half of div that i don't want hidden , but the whole div gone.

```
.line {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.gl {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: green;
    display: block;

}

.rl {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 30px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
}
```

and this html code

```
<div class='m1'>
        MAIN 1
        <div class='line'><div class="rl"></div><div class='gl'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='des'>kasjfnkvanj</div>
</div>
```

i want to hide both lines green and red , only the extend part that overflows the parent div but all of them get hidden

any help?

Comment: like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZMD5N/ ?

Comment: that's what i want, i've just added 3 lines on css :
.m1{
width:60px;
}
and it got like what i want, but in browser it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want hidden overflow green and red background from .line div and this time nothing is showing so you need just fixed parent div ( .line )  width and height.

```
.line {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100px; height:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide green and red background block, but want to show content from div.des. right ? you can do display:none to those div. and if don't want that you can hide them by removing height. If I am understanding this right.

```
height:0;
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMD5N/1/).

Comment: @crazyhila no, i want to hide parts of gl and rl divs that are out of .m1 div

Comment: Then you have to define width/height for .m1 div and overflow:hidden for it. so when something bigger (width/height) will come inside this .m1div that will show only size of .m1 div and overflow part will be hidden. [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMD5N/6/) Try removing .link too then you will see red part too. because now link is 120px and .m1 is 100px so 20px is hidden.